# Why is __exit used in kernel module programming?

Tags: linux-kernel, initialization, kernel-module, init

If there isn't going to be any memory allocation in case the module is built into the kernel or if module unloading is not allowed then why use it in the first place ? Please correct me if I am wrong/assuming anything wrong.

Edit - I am also not able to understand what purpose does `__exit` serve. `module_exit()` should be enough or not ?

Comment: Yeah and I was suggested that this is the appropriate place to post it

Comment: Are you referring to, or have already read, page 9 of the [The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/lkmpg.pdf)?

Comment: I just read it there too but yeah still not clear. Sry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple answer: it's there so you can make a module unloadable without imposing a penalty if your module turns out not to be unloadable (e.g. it's built-in, or the kernel doesn't support module unloading).

Not all modules make sense to unload, but if your driver could feasibly be unloaded, adding support for that makes sense and will make others (who use your drivers) happier.

As for the macro itself: `__exit` expands to a special directive that tells the compiler to discard the function if the module cannot be unloaded. This saves on code space if the exit functions won't be called.